# How do I alter this function so that only one, random song can be played at a time with each click? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, audio-player

I'm essentially building a music generator/player app using HTML, CSS, and vanilla JavaScript where every time a user clicks a particular div with respect to a particular genre of music, a new song from that genre is played. To generate a random song, I created this JS function:

```
const randomizeSongs = playlist => {
    let song = playlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)];
    song.play();
  }
```

The issue I've run into is when I tried using the following code:

```
const pop = document.querySelector(".pop") // Div containing audio elements
pop.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const popSongs = document.querySelectorAll(".pop audio");
      randomizeSongs(popSongs);
})
```

the function generated a new song with each click like I wanted to, but the previous songs generated with previous clicks didn't stop playing. How can I modify the randomizeSongs function so that only one random song can play at a time with each new click?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `pause` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_play.asp).

Haven't tried this but it would look like:

```
let previousSong;
const randomizeSongs = playlist => {
    if (previousSong) {
        previousSong.pause();
    }
    let song = playlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)];
    song.play();
    previousSong = song;
}
```

Comment: Never mind, it does work! I forgot to add the part that says "previousSong = song;". Thank you so much!