# How would I randomly loop through a array/list of songs without repeating previous songs? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, audio

This is a follow-up question to a previous question I've posted on here. I've posted it here just in case: [How do I alter this function so that only one, random song can be played at a time with each click? (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59595192/how-do-i-alter-this-function-so-that-only-one-random-song-can-be-played-at-a-ti/59595259#59595259)

I am building this music generator application using HTML/CSS/JavaScript, and the main functionality is that when a user clicks a particular tile representing a genre of music, *one* song from that particular genre is played at a time. 
Thanks to some helpful SO users, I was able to build a function that would help me do this:

```
let previousSong;
const randomizeSongs = playlist => {
    if (previousSong) {
        previousSong.pause();
        previousSong.currentTime = 0;
    }
    let song = playlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)];
    song.play();
    previousSong = song;
}

const pop = document.querySelector(".pop") // Div containing audio elements
pop.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   let playlist = document.querySelectorAll(".pop audio")
   randomizeSongs(playlist);
 })
```

Although this code works perfectly fine, a problem that I've run into is that although songs were being played randomly, certain songs kept being played over and over again even after multiple clicks while other songs were being ignored. On apps like Spotify or Apple Music, when you shuffle through a playlist of songs, songs *are* played randomly, but they aren't repeated until every other songs has been either played or skipped.

To fix this problem, I wrote this code:

```
  let previousSong;
  const randomizeSongs = playlist => {

    if (previousSong) {

      previousSong.pause();
      previousSong.currentTime = 0;

      let filteredPlaylist = playlist.filter(function(previousSong) {
        return !previousSong;
      })

      if (filteredPlaylist.length >= 1) {
        randomizeSongs(filteredPlaylist);
      }
      else {
        randomizeSongs(playlist);
      }
    }

    let song = playlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)];
    song.play();
    previousSong = song;

  }
```

I've run into a new problem now. Whenever I click a particular div representing a music genre, it picks a random song alright, but with each new click after the first, the console returns: `Uncaught TypeError: playlist.filter is not a function at randomizeSongs`.

I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong or if I'm going in the right direction with my code. Please help.

Comment: What is the shape of playlist before you run randomizeSongs?  What is it after you run randomizeSongs?

Comment: Do not pick random songs. Instead randomize your entire list and then play them sequentially..

Comment: Note that you don’t need to put the tag in the title like you are. The tag box is for tags.

Comment: Also, research “shuffling an array”.

Answer (score 0):

```
let index = 0;
let previousSong = null;
let randomArray = null;

const randomizeSongs = playlist => {

    if(!randomArray) {
        toRandom(playlist);
    }

    if (previousSong) {

        previousSong.pause();
        previousSong.currentTime = 0;

    }

    if(index < randomArray.length) {
        const song = randomArray[index++];
        song.play();
        previousSong = song;
    }else {
        toRandom(playlist);
        index = 0;
        randomizeSongs(playlist);
    }
};

const toRandom = playlist => {

    const count = playlist.length;
    const playlist_copy = playlist.slice();
    randomArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        const rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * playlist_copy.length );

        randomArray.push(playlist_copy.splice(rand, 1))
    }

};
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

You'd generate an array of all audio elements and shuffle that array. Then, loop though the array one by one on each button click, renewing the shuffle once you reach the end. I'd use [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to shuffle the array in a simple and readable way.

```
var playlist = [];
var shuffledPlaylist = [];
var previousSong = false;

function playNextSong(){
    if(previousSong){
        previousSong.pause();
        previousSong.currentTime = 0;
    }

    if(shuffledPlaylist.length == 0) shuffledPlaylist = randoSequence(playlist);

    previousSong = shuffledPlaylist.pop().value;
    previousSong.play();
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    playlist = document.querySelectorAll(".pop audio");
    document.querySelector(".pop").addEventListener("click", playNextSong);
});
```

If you want to use this code, include this in the head tag of your html document to source in randojs functionality:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, `randoSequence(playlist)`, the function call that shuffles `playlist`, won't work. This code also uses JavaScript's [`pop()` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp), which removes the last element of the `shuffledPlaylist` array and returns it so we can store the value in our `previousSong` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have another question. In the code, you put that ```previousSong = shuffledPlaylist.pop().value;```. Right now I'm in the process of creating pause/play functionality, and I need a variable for the current song so when the user presses the spacebar, it either pauses or plays the song currently playing, and not any song that was previously played. How would I define a currentSong variable?

Comment: previousSong really is currentSong, just change the name of it,